# Realtek HD Audio Driver (Beats Audio) issue

Tags: dual-boot, usb, uefi, live-usb, usb-installation

My Laptop is "HP Envy 15-k020us" and this laptop has beats audio enhancement.
I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10. But I noticed that Beats Audio is missing. The sound is too dull. I tried to find a fix for this issue. but couldn't find one. Looks like my laptop sound card driver is not out there. and whichever fix I found on the internet such as installing alsa-tools-gui or pavucontrol not working properly. it is not making a noticeable improvement. I saw hdajackretask to change pin but whichever example I found (for **IDT90...** something) is not matching with my **ALC3241**. My pin is different. 
I ran `sudo dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'` and got below output.

```
System Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP ENVY 15 Notebook PC 
    Version: 0975100000405F10000620180
```

and `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` and got this

```
Codec: Intel Haswell HDMI
Codec: Realtek ALC3241
```

Please help me.